# How to Update button text with Javascript

Tags: javascript, button, text, colors

I have  tried a few different approaches to updating the text colour of a button with javascript but none have worked:

```
document.getElementById(elementID).textContent.fontcolor = "red";
document.getElementById(elementID).textContent.fontcolorstyle = "red";
 document.getElementById(elementID).textContent.style = "red";
```

So my question is how do you access the text of a button and change the colour with JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by changing the `color` styling of the button as follows:

```js
document.getElementById('btn').style.color='red';
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
document.getElementById('btn-id').style.color = 'red'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following:

```
<button id="submit" onclick="textChange()">Click me</button>

function textChange(){
    let btn = document.getElementById("submit");
    btn.style.color = "red";
}

thanks.
```